# SQL Server: query values and show null if no result

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have 3 tables

- **KALENDER** - this table contains a year's calendar and which days we don't work
- **GEOPERS** - this table contains personnel data and their unique usernames
- **GEOTIKKINGEN** - this table contains a timestamp (date and time when someone has used their badge to enter a room)

I'm trying to get a query to return me values like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Date          | Username         | Badge timestamp       |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 01-jan-2018   | Steve            | null                  |
| 01-jan-2018   | Peter            | 01-01-2018T08:25:21   |
| 01-jan-2018   | Sasha            | null                  |
| 02-jan-2018   | Steve            | null                  |
| 02-jan-2018   | Peter            | null                  |
| 02-jan-2018   | Sasha            | null                  |
| 03-jan-2018   | Steve            | 03-01-2018T12:01:20   |
| 03-jan-2018   | Peter            | 03-01-2018T06:39:01   |
| 03-jan-2018   | Sasha            | 03-01-2018T09:11:15   |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The query should go and show results for each value in table `Kalender` and for each person in table `GeoPers` and then show me their badge timestamp and if not then NULL

I have gotten so far:

```
select 
    k.datum, isnull(gp.name,null), isnull(gt.DateTimeLocal,null)
from 
    Kalender k
left outer join 
    GeoTikkingen gt on CAST(k.datum as DATE) = CAST(gt.DateTimeLocal as DATE)
left outer join 
    GeoPers gp on gp.name = gt.UserName
order by 
    k.datum asc, gp.name asc
```

But when a user has not badged on a specific day, it doesn't return NULL

I should be able have a list of all values in Kalender AND all values in GeoPers, have they badged then timestamp if not NULL

Please help :-)

Comment: You are going to need a full outer join between kalendar and geopers instead of a left join.

Comment: The ISNULL function is redundant since you assigning NULL anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should apply `full outer join`;

```
select k.datum, gp.name, gt.DateTimeLocal
from Kalender k
full outer join GeoTikkingen gt on CAST(k.datum as DATE) = CAST(gt.DateTimeLocal as DATE)
full outer join GeoPers gp on gp.name = gt.UserName
order by k.datum asc, gp.name asc
```

And remove `isnull(gt.DateTimeLocal,null)` statement, it is completely in wrong usage.

Comment: that doesn't work, i have 10 servicemen so that means i should have per date 10 badge timestamp, if no timestamp present than it should still result NULL on his name

Comment: So, full join would satisfy that. What do you mean "that doesn't work"

Comment: this is the result i get, doesnt matter if i do full outer join, left outer join or even a full join    [link]https://imgur.com/a/pqbQA

Comment: it should display all the other technicians with value NULL since they didn't work or use their badge, i hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I think `cross join` is the way to go.  Here is something I did to confirm my opinion.  You can adopt it to your database objects:

```
with a as (select 1 record
union select 2 record)
, b as (select 'a' text
union select 'b' text)
,c as (select 1 r
union select 4 r)

select record, text, r
from a cross join b
left join c on record = r
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT k.datum,
       gp.name,
       gt.DateTimeLocal
  FROM Kalender k,
       GeoPers gp
       LEFT OUTER JOIN GeoTikkingen gt
                    ON Cast(k.datum AS DATE) = Cast(gt.DateTimeLocal AS DATE)
                       AND gp.name = gt.UserName
 ORDER BY k.datum ASC,
          gp.name ASC
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "k.datum" could not be bound.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?